# make browser open rather than download pdf

Tags: javascript, http, browser, download

Currently I'm responding to a request with

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=xxx.pdf
```

At frontend, I'm simply appending an iframe to the body with its url pointed to the pdf endpoint

This causes chrome, ff, and opera to download the pdf rather than open it in page

Is there a way to make the browser open the pdf rather than download it?

Comment: Not all browsers *can* directly open a PDF file.

Comment: That's fine; just needs to support those that can

Comment: Try `Content-Disposition: inline; filename=xxx.pdf` or leave out the `Content-Disposition` header altogether.

Comment: Thanks! works great! so is this only possible in chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the browsers are not as advanced as I've thought!
This is only possible in Chrome, or other browsers with relevant plugins.